# data column not recognized in the ggplot geom_hline

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I was wondering why variable `mean_y` is not recognized by my
`geom_hline(yintercept = unique(mean_y))` call?

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(20)
n_groups <- 2
n_in_group <- 20
sd_e = 2
groups <- gl(n_groups, n_in_group, labels = c("T","C"))
age <-rnorm(length(groups), 25, 3)
betas <- c(5,0,0,2)
dat <- data.frame(groups=groups,age=age)

X <- model.matrix(~ groups * age, data = dat)

lin_pred <- as.vector(X %*% betas)

dat$y <- rnorm(nrow(X), lin_pred, sd_e)


dat %>% group_by(groups) %>%  mutate(mean_y = mean(y)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
ggplot()+aes(x = age, y = y) +
  geom_point(aes(color=groups)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = unique(mean_y)) # Error in unique(mean_y) :
                                          # object 'mean_y' not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables need to be inside `aes()`, try:

```
geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean_y))
```

Comment: I removed `unique`

Comment: Inside `aes()` you can define a variable for `group`

Comment: Can be, the first `aes` is global so any aesthetic defined tere you be applied for every geometry, if you want a group for a specific geometry you can define them inside . So it will depend what do you want to do

Comment: Try `dat %>%
  group_by(groups) %>%
  mutate(mean_y = mean(y)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot()+aes(x = age, y = y, group = groups) +
  geom_point(aes(color=groups))+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean_y))`

Comment: That was my point, the use of  `aes(x = age, y = y, group = groups)` or `aes(x = age, y = y)` at the start has no effect.